# Passing variable from dropdown in Django to template

Tags: django, templates, variables, drop-down-menu, view

I have a small project ongoing in Django (still learning it and Python) and have some questions regarding passing a variable in Django.

For example, the user enters some data, the project processes it, and then calculates some simple statistics. I would like to pass a "year" variable through dropdown button, so that the user could choose the year for which the report should be generated.

Some parts of the code:

Models.py:

```
class Fms(models.Model):
...
date = models.DateField()
department = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Department')
```

Views.py:

```
def raport(request):
raport = Fms.objects.filter(date__year='2013').extra(select={'month': "EXTRACT(month FROM date)"}).values('month', 'department').order_by('month').annotate(Count('department'))
return render_to_response ('fmstat/raport.html',
                           {'raport': raport},
                           context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Test button:

```
<div class="bs-docs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-pills">
        <li class="dropdown">
            <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="drop4" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Select year for report <b class="caret"></b></a>
            <ul id="menu1" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="drop4">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="{% url 'fmstat.views.raport' %}">2012</a></li>
```

So how can I do this? Pass it via URL or is there another, simpler way?

Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Update your url pattern to capture the year, update your view to take the year as argument, and update your template to build the url with the year:

```
# urls.py
urlpatterns = ('',
   url(r'^raport/(?<year>\d{4})/?', "fmstat.views.raport"),
   # ...
   )

# views.py 
def raport(request, year):
    raport = Fms.objects.filter(date__year=year).extra(...)
    # ...

# template.html
 (...)
 <li role="presentation">
    <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" 
        href="{% url 'fmstat.views.raport' '2012' %}">2012</a>
 </li>
```